# Error when I run the new Installer file of an Application i created in C#

Tags: c#, .net, exception, installation, resourcebundle

I created a C# installer application. When I try to run the desktop application, it's throwing exceptions and I am not able to get any value in the Combo Box(though remaining code works well). The code when run through Visual Studio 2010 runs perfectly fine. Here is the description of various exceptions I get when I click on the the icon. Can anyone provide some assistance as to why i am getting this?

```
See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.Globalization.CultureNotFoundException: Culture is not supported.
Parameter name: name
????? is an invalid culture identifier.
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(String name, Boolean useUserOverride)
   at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(String name)
   at SampleResourceBundle.Loginpage.fillAppLangueCombo()
   at SampleResourceBundle.Loginpage.Form1_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnLoad(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.OnCreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ContainerControl.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WmShowWindow(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
```

Comment: You have installed your application on same machine, which run VS2010 also? Have you enforced any specific culture in the code?

Comment: @HassanNisar Yes I have installed the application on the same machine which has VS2010. Yes I have SpecificCulture.cs file which I have used for ResourceBundle to change the language from the Combo Box.

Comment: Which Culture you enforce when application loads?

Comment: @HassanNisar                    static void InitResourceBundle()
        {
            ResourceBundle resBundle = ResourceBundle.GetInstance();
            resBundle.LocaleRoot = "SampleResourceBundle.locale"; //where my locale files are

            resBundle.AddResourceFile("Form1");
            resBundle.AddResourceFile("Form2");
            resBundle.AddResourceFile("Form3");

            string culture = Properties.Settings.Default.LastCulture;
            resBundle.Locale = culture;
            Application.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo(culture);

        }

Comment: I hope you can make out the above code.. I have deleted the Form2.resource file.. Do you think that might be the reason for the exception? @HassanNisar

Comment: Possibly, I am not sure about the deletion of form2 resource file. You can comment out `AddResourceFile("Form2")` line for test purpose. Important point is to check what culture you are assigning to `CurrentCulture`. You must see which cultures are supported by your OS.

Comment: For test purpose, modify `Properties.Settings.Default.LastCulture` in the `user.config` file with some test value like (en-GB) and run your application.

Comment: @HassanNisar Yes you're right. I guess the Indian language of Marathi isn't being supported. Do you have any idea how I can make Marathi work? Thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem**: Language CultureInfo enforced is not supported by your Operating System.

**How to Test**:

1. Goto AppData folder in the User settings.
2. Locate application folder and find `User.config` file.
3. Modify value of `Properties.Settings.Default.LastCulture` in XML to any common
   language for example: "en-GB".
4. Test the executable.

> **Solution**: Download language pack for your Operating System.
>
> For Windows 7 language packs can be found here:
> http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/language-packs#lptabs=win7